# What is the PHP apache_child_terminate equivalent in Apache 2?

Tags: php, apache2

I really need to be able to do what I believe [apache_child_terminate](https://www.php.net/apache_child_terminate) does, but apparently it doesn't work when using Apache2 (and that is what I am using... Apache 2 in prefork mode).

Is there an equivalent way I can "get rid of" or kill the currently executing Apache process after I finish fulfilling the current request?

Background:

- There is one particular type of request that I get over 100 times each second. A very small message is returned (just a few characters), but Apache keeps the process around for 4 seconds to allow for subsequent requests to be processed by the same Apache process. I can't lower the 4 second keep alive much more because it affects the performance of all the other PHP pages that have a lot of content and requests. So the idea is that only on that one type of request, I don't want the process to linger for 4 seconds.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: Why do you need to terminate the child? An apache child is INTENDED to process multiple requests before naturally restarting itself.

Comment: Apache (in prefork mode [required for PHP]) creates a new process for every single request unless it comes from the same client. There will never be subsequent requests from the same client with this special case I'm dealing with. The extra 4 seconds the process lives for just causes my server to use nearly 2 GB of memory it doesn't need to be using. @MarcB

Comment: @11101101b: false. Unless you configure it otherwise, there's [MaxRequestsPerChild](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#maxrequestsperchild) - which specifies how many requests a child will handle before automatically killing itself. Apache would be INCREDIBLY slow if it had to fork a new child for every single request that came in.

Comment: You're right @MarcB. I had understood that the mpm prefork mode would create a new process for each request. It uses a separate process for each request (e.g. there are no threads), but it does recycle the processes. I guess that means apache_child_terminate would probably not solve my problems...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so this code basically does the apache_child_terminate() equivalent for Apache 2 by nicely telling the Apache process to die after completing the request:

```
<?php

// Terminate Apache 2 child process after request has been
// completed by sending a "friendly" SIGWINCH POSIX signal (28).
function kill_on_exit() {
 posix_kill( getmypid(), 28 );
}

register_shutdown_function( 'kill_on_exit' );

?>
```

**This did not, however, fix my problem.** I ended up getting the best performance by completely turning off Apache KeepAlive. I added this to my apache2.conf file:

```
KeepAlive Off
```

Now the hundreds of requests per second that I'm getting on a specific page do not tie-up resources for 4 seconds. They complete very fast and the process can be reused for another connection.  The performance I'm getting from the normal pages with lots of content is actually pretty good even though every request is going over a different connection to a different process on the server.